# Reference lambda function Arn from another nested Stack

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

I have two sam applications one 'App1' having a lambda function and another one 'App2' that will consume its Arn to create a permission like the following:

**App2 template:**

```
  Parameters: 
    LambdaFunctionArnFromApp1: 
      Type: String
      Description: The shared value will be passed to this parameter by parent stack. 


  DACAdminsLoginPermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      FunctionName: LambdaFunctionArnFromApp1
      Principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn: !Sub arn:${AWS::Partition}:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${HttpWebServer}/*/*/digitalatcore/admins/login
```

**App1 template:**

```
  LambdaFunctionArnFromApp1:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: 'URL'
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      Handler: app.handler

Outputs:
  LambdaFunctionArnFromApp1:
    Value: !GetAtt LambdaFunctionFromApp1.Arn
    Export:
      Name: LambdaFunctionArnFromApp1
```

When i try to deploy the full stack with sam i get the following error :
"*** was not successfully created: The following resource(s) failed to create: [DACAdminsLoginPermission]. ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS"

Can anyone please help me with this.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming both nested stacks have the same parent stack, you can pass the output from the `App1` stack to the `App2` stack like this:

```
  App1Stack:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: app1-template.yaml

  App2Stack:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: app2-template.yaml
      Parameters:
        LambdaFunctionArnFromApp1: !GetAtt App1Stack.Outputs.LambdaFunctionArnFromApp1
```

Another option could be to use the [ImportValue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html) intrinsic function in your `App2` template to get the export that you defined in the `App1` template: `FunctionName: !ImportValue LambdaFunctionArnFromApp1`

Comment: the !GetAtt didn't work for me as of the ImportValue i didn't test it if i ever try it later i will get back to you

Comment: If !GetAtt does not work, can you add the content of your parent template containing the App1 and App2 stacks to your question?